# Endianess in reading/writing files C

Tags: c, file, binary, operating-system, low-level

I need to copy one file binary file into another in C. All files are UTF-16.

I will receive from the user whether the source (to read from) file is unix, mac, or windows.

Also, I will receive from the user whether the target file (to write to) is unix, mac, or windows.

What should I pay attention to while copying each byte?

I have a buffer `unsigned char buffer[2];` and I copy each byte like this:

```
while (fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,source) != 0) {
        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,target);
}
```

Right now I'm paying attention only to the "line breaker". For example (from unix to mac), I do:

```
if (buffer[0] == 0x000a) {
            buffer[0] = 0x000d;
}
if (buffer[1] == 0x000a) {
            buffer[1] = 0x000d;
}
```

In an attempt to change from `\n` to `\r`.

** I can assume each file will have a BOM at the beginning.

Is there any other thing I should pay attention to while doing this transition? Should I change something in the first BOM chars? Should I check the order of the bytes based on endianness of the computer using the program? Is there any other thing that could wrong?

Thank you

Comment: So you're processing UTF-16 with unknown endianness byte by byte and mangling all the 0d or 0a bytes you encounter? You know those bytes show up in other unicode characters as well, right?

Comment: UTF-16 encoded files come in (at least) three varieties: UTF-16 with a BOM and either endianess possible, UTF-16LE always little endian, no BOM, and UTF-16BE always big endian with no BOM. If using the latter two, you need some way to know which one is being used since you can't check the BOM. Being told the platforms suggests you might be expected to do line-ending conversions, so you'd have to know which is in play.

Comment: You should probably parse the BOM and adjust your handling between big and little based on it. Even if you just want to process newlines.

Comment: You could probably get away with a check 0a/0d + the other byte is zero. 0a00 is nothing and 0d00 is something in Malayalam, if you're not working with that, that should be somewhat safe.

Comment: I can assume the BOM will be present in each file. Should I change then also the BOM in the target file based on which computer the program is running on? 
Should I check for 0x000a or 0xa000 based on the endianness too? 
Should reverse each bit when copying based on endianess?

Comment: "Should" (convert endianness) is a judgement that depends on your needs and on the software that will consume these files afterwards, I don't think you've given us enough information to judge it for you. Personally, I've never seen a big-endian utf-16 file in the wild, my instinct would be to convert everything to little. Because I doubt the authors of other software have seen one and are probably not handling that correctly.

Comment: Are the files binary, or UTF-16? They aren't both. Which one are they?

Comment: "Is there any other thing that could wrong? --> Post the code that opens the file.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other thing I should pay attention to while doing this transition?

OP is assuming the OS dictates the file endidan and line ending.

There is a *tendency* for the OS to use a particular endian and line ending, but this tool should not blindly follow that and instead use OS dependent defaults when other overriding info is not provided.

Allowing this ability will facilitate testing.

---

When the input file itself has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), the endian is not determined by the OS, but by the BOM.  When a BOM is missing or unknown, for now, simply quit or *maybe* assume OS default endian.

The input end-of-line (LF, CR, CRLF) can be determined by survey, perhaps as simple as looking for the first end-of-line.

The output endian should follow a program option such as "big", "little", "same as input", "Mac", "Unix", "Windows".  If the option is missing or "default", then use a default endian per OS.

The output end-of-line should follow a program option such as "LF", "CRLF", "CR", "same as input".  If the option is missing or "default", then use a default end-of-file per OS.

Given these options, files likely need to be opened in binary mode.  If working in "default" mode, code could open independently input and/or output in UTF16 text mode and use wide functions and let the library handle endian/end-of-line.

---

Other ideas:

Cope with no input BOM.

Write without a BOM.

Tolerate a final ^Z at the end as a non-character.

Append a ^Z

Detect invalid UTF-16 sequences: Odd number of bytes, invalid surrogate pairs.

---

IIRC, the "Mac" end-of-line depend on its OS version.

---

Summary: create a universal reader that figures out input and forms configurable output.